# como ocultar un elemento que se hizo visible con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, funciones

tengo un menu que despliega informacion cuando se lo clickea y se oculta cuando se abre otro (eso funciona bien) lo que no logro es que al volver a clickearlo se cierre y quede todo como al inicio. Esto es lo que intente pero no hace nada...

```
function desplegar(elemento) {
if($("div.introMenu.mostrar").length > 0) {
  $("div.introMenu.mostrar").removeClass("mostrar"); /** Con esto se elimina la clase mostrar del elemento que la tenga */
}
  if($("div.introMenu.mostrar")[0] != $(elemento).next('div')[0]){ /**ESTO ES LO QUE INTENTE AGREGAR Y NO FUNCIONA*/
  $(elemento).next('div').toggleClass("mostrar");  
}      
}
```

```js
function desplegar(elemento) {
  if ($("div.introMenu.mostrar").length > 0) {
    $("div.introMenu.mostrar").removeClass("mostrar"); /** Con esto se elimina la clase mostrar del elemento que la tenga */
  }
  $(elemento).next('div').toggleClass("mostrar");
}
```

```css
main #seccion {
  margin-bottom: 190px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

main #seccion.sinFooter {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  top: 250px;
}


/*--boton principal de cada seccion--*/

main nav ol li {
  list-style: none;
}

main nav ol li h2 {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0199f5;
  font-family: 'EncodeThin';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d3d5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main nav ol li h2:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: '\ea0a';
  font-size: .5em;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: -3px;
}

main nav ol li h2:hover {
  color: #fbd30c;
  background: #666;
}


/*--desplegable de cada seccion--*/

main nav ol li div.introMenu {
  font-size: .8em;
  display: none;
}

main nav ol li div a {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
}


/*--titulo desplegable--*/

main nav ol li div h3 {
  padding: 3px 0;
}


/*--texto desplegable--*/

main nav ol li div p {
  padding: 5px 0;
}


/*--boton ver mas desplegable--*/

main nav ol li div h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #b5de0a;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*--estilo de display para onclick--*/

main nav ol li div#meta.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#responsive.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#catalogo.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#tienda.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#blog.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#diseno.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#precios.mostrar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <nav id="seccion">
      <ol>
        <li>
          <h2 onClick="desplegar(this)">Que hacemos?</h2>
          <div class="introMenu" id='meta'>
            <a href="nuestra_meta.php">
              <h3>No sabes por donde empezar...</h3>
              <p>Tranquilo! Junto a TIMON DIGITAL vas a lograr adaptarte al mundo de hoy y poder conectar con tus clientes, brindandoles lo que necesitan</p>

              <h4>Ver más +</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2 onClick="desplegar(this)">Diseños adaptables</h2>
          <div class="introMenu" id='responsive'>
            <a href="diseno_responsive.php">
              <h3>Nuevas formas de conectarse...</h3>
              <p>En la vida de hoy, los teléfonos son una extensión de nosotros, y tu negocio no puede quedar afuera de esta tendencia cada vez mas grande. </p>
              <h4>Ver más +</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esconder o mostrar el div inmediatamente debajo del h2, puedes usar toggle que se encargará de esconder o mostrar el elemento, mientras que con el selector not() puedes ocultar directamete los otros elementos:

```js
function desplegar(elemento) {
    $(elemento).next('div').toggle();
    $(".introMenu").not($(elemento).next('div')).hide();
}
```

```css
main #seccion {
  margin-bottom: 190px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

main #seccion.sinFooter {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  top: 250px;
}


/*--boton principal de cada seccion--*/

main nav ol li {
  list-style: none;
}

main nav ol li h2 {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0199f5;
  font-family: 'EncodeThin';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d3d5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main nav ol li h2:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: '\ea0a';
  font-size: .5em;
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: -3px;
}

main nav ol li h2:hover {
  color: #fbd30c;
  background: #666;
}


/*--desplegable de cada seccion--*/

main nav ol li div.introMenu {
  font-size: .8em;
  display: none;
}

main nav ol li div a {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
}


/*--titulo desplegable--*/

main nav ol li div h3 {
  padding: 3px 0;
}


/*--texto desplegable--*/

main nav ol li div p {
  padding: 5px 0;
}


/*--boton ver mas desplegable--*/

main nav ol li div h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #b5de0a;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*--estilo de display para onclick--*/

main nav ol li div#meta.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#responsive.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#catalogo.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#tienda.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#blog.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#diseno.mostrar {
  display: block;
}

main nav ol li div#precios.mostrar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <nav id="seccion">
      <ol>
        <li>
          <h2 onClick="desplegar(this)">Que hacemos?</h2>
          <div class="introMenu" id='meta'>
            <a href="nuestra_meta.php">
              <h3>No sabes por donde empezar...</h3>
              <p>Tranquilo! Junto a TIMON DIGITAL vas a lograr adaptarte al mundo de hoy y poder conectar con tus clientes, brindandoles lo que necesitan</p>

              <h4>Ver más +</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2 onClick="desplegar(this)">Diseños adaptables</h2>
          <div class="introMenu" id='responsive'>
            <a href="diseno_responsive.php">
              <h3>Nuevas formas de conectarse...</h3>
              <p>En la vida de hoy, los teléfonos son una extensión de nosotros, y tu negocio no puede quedar afuera de esta tendencia cada vez mas grande. </p>
              <h4>Ver más +</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: buenisimo, muchas gracias @track3r, una consulta mas: quisiera que cuando se hace click en cualquier parte de la ventana se cerrara tambien la pestaña, eso es posible?

Comment: Supongo, añade un evento al body por ejemplo que haga un hide de .introMenu: $("body").click(function() { $(".introMenu").hide(); });

Comment: O escrito de otra forma <body onClick="ocultar()"> y una function ocultar() { $(".introMenu").hide(); }

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, pueda que interfiera con la otra función, igual no se puede tal cual... debería hacer pruebas, qué tal si pruebas y si no te sale abres otra pregunta?

Comment: probé y no funciona de esa manera. abro otra pregunta ;) gracias igual!